# How to apply SelectKBest in azure machine learning

Tags: feature-selection, azure-ml

I am very new to machine learning, I started to understand fundamental and using it in `azure studio`, I see that there is an algorithm in `scikit` for feature selection called `SelectKBest`, then I searched azure studio and I coudn't find it by name, I was wondering if is it supported there?

Comment: I am not familiar with azure studio but from I just read it will clearly let you run sklearn modules.  Why would you expect sklearn would be documented in azure studio?  Do you have a link?

Comment: @StephenRauch thanks for comment, I am not expecting sklern be documented in azure studio, I am looking for SelectKBest algorithm in there to be able using it, btw I found another algorithm for feature selection there

Answer (score 1):

I have found there are other feature selection algorithms there

Please see the below screen shots

[image]

[image]